# How to calculate the gradient magnitude , orientation and threshold the image intensity values = [10 20 5],[10 20 5] kx=[1 -1] ky=[1 ], [-1]

Tags: gradient-descent

**How to calculate the gradient magnitude , orientation and threshold the image intensity** values = [10   20   5],[10   20   5] kx=[1   -1] ky=[1 ], [-1]
image intensity values = [10   20   5]
[10   20   5]
kernel for x=[1   -1]

kernel for y=[1 ],
[-1]